# Permanently sort SQL table not result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, sql-server-2014

I want to sort my table permanently by using ID column in ascending order.

`select * from CLAIMS order by ID asc;` gives me the result in ascending order.

But I want to permanently change my table. I am using SQL Management Studio 2014.

Comment: You can *cluster* the data so it is stored in sorted order.  That said, a query -- even a simple query -- on the data is not guaranteed to return the data in any particular order.

Comment: [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Answer (score 3):

While there's no way to guarantee ordered result without an ORDER BY clause on your query, but you can store the rows in a sorted order to enable the SQL Server to run

```
select * from CLAIMS order by ID asc;
```

without having to perform a sort every time.  To do that simply create a clustered index with ID as the only or the leading column.

EG

```
  alter table CLAIMS add constraint PK_CLAIMS primary key clustered (ID)
```

or

```
 create unique clustered index AK_CLAIMS on CLAIMS(ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to sort my table permanently

You just can't. SQL tables represent *unordered set of rows*. There is no inherent ordering of rows in a table, as you seem to assume.

If you want the rows returned in a given order for a *given query*, then do add an `order by` clause to the query:

```
select * from claims order by id
```

If you don't provide an `order by` clause, the database is free to return the rows in whichever order it likes. The ordering you see today for a given query might change unexpectedly in the future.